# Проблема при микшировании звука в караоке-приложении iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, аудио

Привет. У меня стоит задача: сделать караоке-приложение на iOS. Суть в том, что нужно подгружать видео с ютуба и по нажатии на клавишу плей запускать видео и запись на микрофоне. Возникает проблема при микшировании звука. Стоит ли перенаправлять проигрываемый звук на микрофон (то есть чтобы микрофон как бы писал голос и писал проигрываемый звук) - и как это сделать? Или есть какие-то более оптимальные подходы?,

Answer (score 1):

Нет, этого делать не нужно. Что нужно именно Вам, это узнать что такое частота основного тона, как ее вычислить (быстрое преобразование Фурье, если я не ошибаюсь), потом брать частоту основного тона, от идеала исполнения этой песни, и находить основную частоту тона голоса исполняющего, и сравнивать две этих величины, вычисляя процент их совпадения с определенной погрешностью. Если же вы хотите накладывать голос на мелодию, например для прослушивания, то вам просто нужно выгребать голос из входящего в динамик звука (у голоса есть определенная черта, по которой вы можете отличить голос от мелодии), и накладывать его на минус.